# How can I get f.submit's name parameter in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created _form.html.erb, in which it's coded like this

```
<%= form_for @book, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
....
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :name => 'update' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Destroy', :class => 'btn btn-danger', :name => 'destroy' %>
....
<% end %>
```

Yes, I do have 2 submits in the same form, and both of them have name such as 'update' and 'destroy'.

When the user press destroy button, update action in books_controller will be called.
and it judges whether if it's 'update' or 'destroy' request.
For that, how can I get its name parameter in controller?

update action will be something like this

```
def update

 if params[:books][:name] == 'destroy'
  destroy transaction
 else
  update transaction
 end

end
```

Comment: try to inspect what you have in your params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-primary', :name => 'submit' %>
<%= f.submit 'Destroy', :class => 'btn btn-danger', :name => 'submit' %>
```

Now when you **Update** you will get `params[:submit]` as "Update" and
 when you **Destroy** you will get `params[:submit]` as "Destroy" in your controller

Answer (score 0):

When Destroying, do you need the other input values of the form ?

It would be easier (and cleaner) to have two forms, one with the inputs targetting the update action and one with only the destroy button targetting the destoy action ?

If you *need* to access the other inputs, I would still suggest you to have two different actions and two different forms, I would additionally suggest you to use JS / jQuery to fetch the values of the fields you need from the first form when submitting the second form

Comment: Thanks I considered about that but I didn't want to place 2 captcha images for each form:(