# How to mention different action in form on two submit tags?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have my form tag and also i have two buttons in my form. How do i call different actions in my form on click of submit buttons.

Here is my code:

```
<%= form_for :attachment_metadata, :url=>{:action=>'delete_files'}, :html=>{:onsubmit=> "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete selected files?');",:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   <table>
     ..........Some stuff here..........
   </table> 
<%= submit_tag 'Reprocess', :class =>'button' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Remove', :class =>'button' %>
<% end %>
```

On click of "Reprocess" i want to call different action but in same form.

How can i do this?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987512/how-can-i-get-f-submits-name-parameter-in-controller/13988021#13988021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:commit]` can differentiate the actions of two submit tags.
Updated:

> @action = params[:commit]

it gives @`action` value as "`Reprocess`"  if your click the `Reprocess` button and gives "`Remove`" value if you click the `Remove` button,

Comment: You can use it in your submit action. You can differentiate which button is clicked by using params[:commit], it gives the value of your clicked butten, just check

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in [Railscast 38](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form). M sure it will solve your problem. Its very simple. Whenever your have submit a form, it will send some information in params hash about the commit you have performed, i would suggest you to have a look at railscast and you will completely understand.

Comment: I want to call reprocess action on submit of reprocess button

Comment: m sure you can make a call, just have a look at railscast.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different form and you can submit your form using jQuery. in this case you can submit a form to a specific location.

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```